# Deserializing JSON with an array of No Member Name into custom Java object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a long JSON file with different types of objects I need to create from it.
Two types of custom objects are given as an array of strings and an array of ints:

```
"Custom1": ["type1", "type1", "type2", "type3"]
"Custom2": [10,10,20,20,20]
```

Custom1 and Custom2 have their own classes with constructors.

I have made a Wrapper class that handles storing all the the objects the Gson creates using the JSON file I have. All objects that has member names work as intended.

When I try this in the Wrapper:

```
ArrayList<Custom1> cusOne;
ArrayList<Custom2> cusTwo;
```

I get a long string of errors. these objects have constructors that receive string / int (respectively).

But when I use this in the wrapper:

```
ArrayList<String> GPUS;
ArrayList<Integer> CPUS;
```

It works. I would like the Custom objects to be created directly in the wrapper, and to avoid created them after the fact. I feel like that is something that should be possible but I couldn't find info about it.
I would appreciate any advise as to how it can be done.

the code:

```
public static class Wrapper { //etc objects are the ones I can create normally.
    ArrayList<Etc> Etc; 
    ArrayList<String> CusOne;
    ArrayList<Integer> CusTwo;
    ArrayList<Etc2> Etc2;
    int Etc3;
    int Etc4;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Wrapper wrapper;
    try {
        wrapper = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(args[0]), Wrapper.class);
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(wrapper));
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("IOException");
    }
}
public class Custom1{
/**
 * Enum representing the type of the Custom.
 */
enum Type {type1, typ2, Type3}

private Type type;
private Model model;
private Cluster cluster;
- constructors, getters and setters -
}
public class Custom2{
private int count;
private Vector<DataBatch> data;
private Cluster cluster;
- constuctors, getters and setters -
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the code for `Custom1` and `Custom2`? Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias added the code for them, didnt include setters getters and constructors because they're pretty default.

Comment: You will definitely need a custom serializer for that. Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide.

Comment: @JoãoDias That would mean I would need to manually extract every piece of data in the JSON and create all the object one by one, correct?

Comment: Yes, I would say that is the only option. Or at least is the only one I am aware of.